# Filling space between two curves with random points

Tags: plotting, graphics, random

How can I fill the blue space between two curves, for example $\sin$ and $\cos$, with random points? What if they are two `BezierCurve`s instead of functions?

[image: sine and cosine]

Comment: Try this: `Graphics[Point[RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[Cos[x] <= y <= Sin[x] || Sin[x] <= y <= Cos[x], {{x, 0, 2 π}, {y, -1, 1}}], 1*^4]]]`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution equivalent to the one posted in the comments:

```
With[{n = 1*^4}, 
     Graphics[{Directive[Blue, AbsolutePointSize[1]], 
               Point[RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[Between[y, {{Cos[x], Sin[x]},
                                                            {Sin[x], Cos[x]}}],
                                                {{x, 0, 2 π}, {y, -1, 1}}], n]]},
              Frame -> True]]
```

[image: random points between sine and cosine]

(Note that this throws a redundant `RandomPoint::unbndreg` message, even tho bounds have been explicitly specified in `ImplicitRegion[]`. You can ignore it here.)

Comment: It really shows amazing capabilities of Mathematica.