# Fill space between two BezierCurves with random points

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, splines

I asked a question about [filling the space between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143874/filling-space-between-two-curves-with-random-points) (`Sin` and `Cos`) with random points and the answer I received does not work for `InterpolatingFunction`s. How can I fill the space between two `BezierCurve`s or `InterpolatingFunction`s?

For example, I have the `BezierCurve`s `c1` and `c2`:

```
c1 = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
c2 = {{0, 0.25}, {1.75, 0.25}, {1.75, 1}};

Graphics[{BezierCurve@c1,BezierCurve@c2}]
```

I can use `RandomPoint` by turning these curves into a `Polygon`:

```
f[c_] := Quiet@
   Interpolation[BezierFunction[c][#] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01]];
g[c_] := {#, f[c][#]} & /@ Range[0, c[[-1, 1]], 0.01];

h1 = Join[{c2[[1]]}, g@c1]; h2 = Join[g@c2, {c1[[-1]]}];

Graphics[{
  Point@RandomPoint[Polygon@Join[h1, h2], 500],
  Thick, Line@h1, Line@h2
  }]
```

[image]

My question is, is there a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: To people trying to solve this: [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98147) is a possible pitfall to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

- Only add a `Line` and set `CurveClosed -> True` to draw a closed contour.

```
c1 = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
c2 = {{0, 0.25}, {1.75, 0.25}, {1.75, 1}};

reg = JoinedCurve[{BezierCurve@c1, Line[{Last@c1, Last@c2}], 
     BezierCurve@Reverse@c2}, CurveClosed -> True] // 
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics;
Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[LightGreen], reg}, Red, 
  Point@RandomPoint[reg, 200]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with sorcery...

```
c1 = {{2, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}};
c2 = {{0, 0.25}, {1.75, 0.25}, {1.75, 1}};
gk = JoinedCurve[{Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.25}}], BezierCurve@c2, 
Line[{{1.75, 1}, {2, 1}}], BezierCurve@c1}];
Graphics[{Black, 
FilledCurve[{BezierCurve@c1, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.25}}], 
BezierCurve@c2, Line[{{1.75, 1}, {2, 1}}]}], White, 
Point[RandomPoint[Disk[{1, 0.45}, {1.3, 0.9}], 5000]]}]
```

[image: :)]

Answer (score 1):

*(Not an answer -- a comment/follow-up of the answer by @cvgmt.)*

I expected `NIntegerate` to work also for this.

```mathematica
c1 = {{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}};
c2 = {{0, 0.25}, {1.75, 0.25}, {1.75, 1}};

reg = JoinedCurve[{BezierCurve@c1, Line[{Last@c1, Last@c2}], 
     BezierCurve@Reverse@c2}, CurveClosed -> True] // 
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics;

res = Reap@
  NIntegrate[x, x \[Element] reg, Method -> "MonteCarlo", 
   PrecisionGoal -> 1.2, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x}]]
```

But it gives the monitored point unevaluated:

```mathematica
{{0.596312, 0.204349}, {{{x}, {x}, {x}, {x},...
```

This work around can be used, but that is suboptimal:

```mathematica
res = Reap@
   NIntegrate[x*Boole[{x, y} \[Element] reg], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    Method -> "MonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> 1.2, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y}]];

Graphics[Point@Pick[res[[2, 1]], # \[Element] reg & /@ res[[2, 1]]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me: `res = Reap@NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> "MonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> 1.2, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow@{x, y}];`

Comment: @Goofy Thank you! Good to know!